# passport.authenticate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Hello I am new in NodeJs and I have been following this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619 to create a app with authenticating.
I tried to follow all the structre and code from the tutorial (code is on github https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo) but when I open my app in browser
i get error this error

> TypeError: passport.authenticate is not a function
>       at module.exports (C:\myApp\routes\index.js:24:34)

This is my index.js route file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler
  // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
  // request and response objects
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
  res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = function(passport){

  /* GET login page. */
  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
    res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
  });

  /* Handle Login POST */
  router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash : true
  }));

  /* GET Registration Page */
  router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
  });

  /* Handle Registration POST */
  router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
  }));

  /* GET Home Page */
  router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('home', { user: req.user });
  });

  /* Handle Logout */
  router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  return router;
}
```

Probabbly the problem is there, maybe routing was change in some version of express, but I cant figure out what is the problem.
Can you help pme please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had same problem. Look at app.js. There must be:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
```

Answer (score -3):

You have just put the parenthesis at the wrong place.
It should be

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login'), {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash : true
  });
```